# Cannot receive "Referral" traffic with any of my analytics software?

Tags: analytics

I have tried Matomo (Piwiki), Counter.Dev, GoatCounter, Cloudfare, Plauisbile Analytics, SatCounter, and a few other services (hosted and self-hosted)

For some reason, I cannot get any of these programs to reveal my referral traffic. They always just show my visitations as "Direct" and do not show where they came from.

What could be the cause of this? Any help would be greatly appreciated?

Answer (score 1):

Any link with rel="noreferrer" will not include the referral and show as direct when they reach your page.

```
<a href="HTTP://www.example.com" rel="noreferrer">show as direct</a>
```

No software on your site can determine where a visitor to the page came from there is "no referral" information presented in the header of the HTTP request.

In addition traffic from HTTPS pages generally does not provide referral information.

The only referrals you can expect are from HTTP sites not using rel="noreferrer" on their links ... Advertisement cookies can when and if both sites are using the same source and track people from site to site, but they are under heavy pressure to stop doing so by many governments.

### Update to opt-in to sending referrals

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy

```
<meta name="referrer" content="origin" />
```

or

```
<a href="http://example.com" referrerpolicy="origin">…</a>
```

You can specify the referrerpolicy attribute on a, area, img, iframe, script, or link elements to set referrer policies for individual requests:

### Note new default referrer policy

> [https://developer.chrome.com/blog/referrer-policy-new-chrome-default/#:~:text=strict%2Dorigin%2Dwhen%2Dcross%2Dorigin%20offers%20more%20privacy,the%20path%20and%20query%20string](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/referrer-policy-new-chrome-default/#:%7E:text=strict%2Dorigin%2Dwhen%2Dcross%2Dorigin%20offers%20more%20privacy,the%20path%20and%20query%20string).
>
> Chrome plans to gradually enable strict-origin-when-cross-origin as
> the default policy in 85; this may impact use cases relying on the
> referrer value from another origin.

Comment: Yeah I know about rel="noreferrer", but I am not using it. For simplicity, I have 2 websites -- one linking to the other -- and I still can't get any analytics software to my referrer.

Comment: However, when I use https://whatsmyreferer.com/ -- my referring URL is shown fine, not sure what I am missing.

Comment: If you follow a link from site one to site two and look at dev tools > network > the index.html or resource in the list> headers tag > request headers > referer ... is the information there?

Comment: There doesn't appear to be for some reason. I tried entering in 'document.referrer' into the console and I receive nothing but a blank quotations.

Comment: If its not there a script can not log it. "Direct" means the software has received nothing but a blank in quotations. Should I presume that you are following a link from a https page? links from HTTP pages still present referral information.

Comment: Is there a difference between HTTP and HTTPs when it comes to referrals?

Comment: Yes the Default referrer policy https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-referrer-policy/#referrer-policy-header is no-referrer-when-downgrade https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/http-headers-referrer-policy/#:~:text=Information%20is%20sent%20for%20HTTPS,origin%20(different%20website)%20requests. bottom line is there is no referral to log.

Comment: If you want to opt-in to sending referrals from https->https you can add <meta name="referrer" content="origin" /> to your html page. But I don't expect this to be a common practice.